# How to print an infix from a binary expression tree with necessary parentheses?

Tags: java, binary-tree, infix-notation

I'm working on printing an infix expression from my binary tree. However I can display the form in fully parenthesized form but the question is asking to only print the necessary parentheses.

For example, consider the expression `7 2 8 - - 9 3 * +`. The postfix form can be printed in fully parenthesized:

```
((7 - (2 - 8)) + (9 * 3))
```

Or it can be printed with necessary parentheses:

```
7 - (2 - 8) + 9 * 3
```

What I coded for that is...

```
public Node root;

public void infix() {
    infix(root);
}

public void infix(Node r) {
    if (r != null) {
        if (r.left != null && r.right != null) {  //Check if it is a leaf
            System.out.print ("(");
        }
        infix(r.left);
        System.out.print(r.data);
        infix(r.right);
        if (r.left != null && r.right != null) {  //Check if it is a leaf
            System.out.print (")");
        }
    }
}
```

But I have no idea that how to do this. Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: Can you explain in English when parentheses are required?

Comment: @JohnKugelman Displaying the arithmetic expression in the infix form needs to use parentheses to make explicit the ordering of operations. Some of the parentheses are not necessary. For example, `7 - 2 - 8` and `7 - (2 - 8)` are different. Since according to the postfix form given, arithematically, `2 - 8 (-6)`has to be evaluated first and then uses the result to calculate `7 - (-6)`. But we don't need any parentheses to indicate `( 9 * 3 )` or `( 7 - (2 - 8) )`.

Comment: this could help http://scanftree.com/Data_Structure/postfix-to-infix

Comment: Scan up the tree to see if there are operators that could cause ambiguities. Or track that as you recurse.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need the concept of the 'precedence level' of the current operator. For example, at the root or when the current operator is `+` or `-`, the level is 0, but when the current operator is `*` or `/`, the level is 1. You need to add the current level as a parameter to the recursive method. Then you know that you need parentheses when the inner operator (e.g. `+`) has a lower precedence level than the outer operator (e.g. `*`).

Comment: It also depends whether the child operator is on the left or right and which operations are associative.   These parens are required: 1 - (2 - 3) ,  1 + (2 - 3), 1 - (2 + 3).  These are not: 1 + (2 + 3),  (1 - 2) + 3, (1 + 2) - 3

Comment: If the evaluation order is to be retained, parentheses in 1 + (2 + 3) is also required to make the evaluation order different from 1+2+3 (assume + has left associativity).